# JavaScript scrollIntoView within a Scroll event

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

The goal is to create a full page scroll without using any libraries.

I've tried using the CSS `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` which actually works fine on desktop.

HTML:

```
  <div id="scroll_snap_container">
    <section id="section-1">
      content 
    </section>
    <section id="section-2">
      content
    </section>
    .
    .
    .
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
  #scroll_snap_container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    section {
      position: relative;
      height: 100vh;
   }
 }
```

However on iOS mobile devices it triggers multiple issues.

1. The scrolling often get's stuck once the user reaches the bottom of the page. As the browser acts as if the window would be scrolled but in reality the user tries to scroll the `#scroll_snap_container`.
2. The second major issue is safari's (browser) searchbar which is located at the bottom of the page. This searchbar usually disappears on scroll down. Which again, because we are not actually scrolling the window but a container, is not triggered. This reduces availably space and breaks the 100vh calculation as the searchbar overlaps with the content.

Workaround (not working):
using JavaScript.
JavaScript has a `scrollIntoView` event. Which works perfectly when triggered on click. As you might have guessed. I do not want the user to click every time to move on. The idea is to use the

```
      element.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
          const section2 = document.getElementById("section-2");
          if ((window.scrollY > 100) && !this.isScrollingState) {
             section2.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
             this.isScrollingState = true;
          }
      });
```

(Yes this needs to be more dynamic)
I figured that using some kind of verifier / `state` in this case is necessary as the event will trigger a trillion times as soon as the window is scrolled more than 100 causing the animation to be really slow.
But as soon as there is only one trigger it is ignored as soon as the user scrolls on.
Simply put, the `scrollIntoView`is only triggered if the user let's go of the scrolling at exactly `window.scrollY > 100`. if you scroll let's say 104 the event is already ignored.

I'm using Vue3 (for the first time) and can't trigger the `update method` which might be another option I can imagine it working in a `componentDidUpdate` in react.

Also how would you make this more dynamic? Scroll up, Scroll down -> next section accordingly.

Comment: *"because we are not actually scrolling the window but a container, is not triggered."* It's because the scroll event is not bubbling up from the ```#scroll_snap_container``` to the window, so why don't use ```touchmove``` instead of the ```scroll```? ```element.addEventListener('touchmove', function() { .. }```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this doesn't really make a difference. But tbh this only happens when the user penetrates the scrolling, so for the moment the bigger issue is the searchbar wich isn't hiding